# Run Bash-Script within Electron App using child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, bash, electron, child-process

I'm struggling with running a bash-script within main.html.

```
 const exec = require("child_process").exec;

 // Execute bash script
 exec("/c/workspace/_edu_zone/Proxy_Manager/filemover.sh", shellCallback);

 // Callback
 function shellCallback(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(error, stdout)
 }
```

I'm always getting the error: no such file or directory. What am i doing wrong?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: change /c/workspace/_edu_zone/Proxy_Manager/filemover.sh to c:/workspace/_edu_zone/Proxy_Manager/filemover.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
/c/workspace/_edu_zone/Proxy_Manager/filemover.sh
```

to

```
c:/workspace/_edu_zone/Proxy_Manager/filemover.sh
```

or

your could try using node-powershell to execute the command directly

```
const shell = require('node-powershell')

let ps = new shell({
    executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
    noProfile: true
});

function lunchnode() {
    process.stdout.write('logging');
    ps.addCommand('node run.js')
    ps.invoke()
   .then(function (output) {
       process.stdout.write(output)
   }).catch(function (err) {
       process.stdout.write(err)
       ps.dispose()
   })   
}
```